# How to create a list of fields in django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is there any way to make a django forms class that actually holds an array of fields?  I have a database that will pull up a variable number of questions to ask the user and each question will know how to define it's widget...etc, I just can't seem to hook this up to django forms.

I tried this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    question = []
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    for q in questions:
        question.append(forms.CharField(max_length=100, label=q.questionText))
```

But this doesn't seem to expose my questions list when I create a new instance of `MyForm`.  Is there any way to get a variable number of form fields using django forms, or is this beyond the scope of what it can do?

Comment: Have you thought about using a factory pattern with form classes themselves? You can process any number of forms in a view, which could be in a list.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may be able to use [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) if your forms are identical (including their labels). e.g.

Question: __________________
Question: __________________
Question: __________________

etc. I'm assuming each form contains only one field here (the 'Question' field). There are three forms in this example.

---

If you need a dynamic number of fields in a *single* form, then you can use `__init__` to achieve what you want (note: untested code!):

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        questions = kwargs.pop('questions')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        counter = 1
        for q in questions:
            self.fields['question-' + str(counter)] = forms.CharField(label=question)
            counter += 1
```

And you'd create the form with something like:

```
form = MyForm(questions=your_list_of_questions)
```

You'll find this article useful: http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/

Comment: Nice article, I think the `self.fields[''] =` logic is what I was really missing (at least the easiest way to get from where I am to where I want to be).  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 6):

Of course you can!

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i, q in enumerate(Question.objects.all()):
            self.fields['%s_field' % i] = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label=q.questionText)
```

Note: make sure your questions are ordered between calls.. as the field list will be repopulated upon form submission, receipt, etc.

If the data is ordered and static, it won't be a problem.

Also you may want to look into `FormSet`s, a list of forms which may be more fitting in your case.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia: I would go with formsets if i were you