# How to register multiple fields from a loop in a forms?

Tags: python, django, forms, loops

How can I do to record responses to questions by looping ?
I possess several questions and I would answer all powers at the same time creating a loop that gets me every
I can create a loop for each question and each answer but when validating the form it does not register in my database ...

> So this is my models.py :

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    page = models.ManyToManyField(Page)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.label

class Reply(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Personne)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

> and my templates :

```
<center><h3> Formulaire de la {{ numPages }} pour lutilisateur : <center>{{ logged_user|upper }}.</center> </h3></center>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- {{ form.as_p }} -->
  <p>
    {% for question in questions %}<hr>
    <label for="question">{{ question }}</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="id_question_{{ question.id }}" name="question" value="{{ question.id }}"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="answer">Réponse :</label>
    <input type="text" id="id_answer_{{ question.id }}" name="answer" />
  </p>  
    {% endfor %}<hr>
  <p>
    <label for="creationDate">Date de création :</label>
    <input type="text" id="id_creationDate" name="creationDate" />
  </p> 
  <p>
    <label for="user"> User : {{ logged_user }}</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="id_user" name="user" /><!-- <select name="{{ logged_user }}" size="1">
      <option id="{{ logged_user.id }}">{{ logged_user }}</option>
    </select> -->
  </p>
  <p>
  <br><br><br>
    <center><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" /></center>
  </p>
</form>
```

> and my views.py :

```
def access(request,instance):
    replies = Reply.objects.all()
    logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
    numPages = Page.objects.get(pk=instance)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(page=instance)
    pagesfilter = Question.objects.get(pk=1) # PEUT ETRE CHANGER SE FILTRE - A VOIR
    # pagesfilter = Page.objects.get(pk=instance).reply_set.filter(user=logged_user) # PEUT ETRE CHANGER SE FILTRE - A VOIR
    form = ReplyForm(request.GET)
    personnes = Personne.objects.all()
    if logged_user:
        if len(request.POST) > 0:
            form = ReplyForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.cleaned_data['user']
                question = form.cleaned_data['question']
                answer = form.cleaned_data['answer']
                form.save(commit=True)
                return HttpResponse(form.cleaned_data["user"])
            else:
                return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {'logged_user':logged_user, 'pagesfilter': pagesfilter, 'numPages': numPages, 'personnes': personnes, 'replies': replies, 'questions': questions, 'form': form})
        else:
            form = ReplyForm()
            return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {'logged_user':logged_user, 'pagesfilter': pagesfilter, 'numPages': numPages, 'personnes':personnes, 'replies': replies, 'questions': questions, 'form': form})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
```

> My forms.py

```
class ReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reply
        fields = ('question','answer','user')
```

> EDIT url :

```
url(r'^baseVisite/$', views.baseVisite),
url(r'^access/(?P<instance>[0-9]+)/$', views.access),
```

**Why my submit button does not work, what I forgot?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "submit button does not work"?

Comment: @Hâken When i click on submit i have a good redirection but the information gone in responses does not register in my database

Comment: Have you tried to step through your view function with pdb?   https://mike.tig.as/blog/2010/09/14/pdb/
Try to isolate your bug and create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: **You want to update many records by using ModelForm : you can't**. 
In your example, only **{{ form.as_p }}** fields will work.
You should use standard form like this post : [How to create a list of fields in django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159567/how-to-create-a-list-of-fields-in-django-forms)

Your syntax template is wrong. Your **p** tag is out your **for** loop.

Try this instead :

```
<center><h3> Formulaire de la {{ numPages }} pour lutilisateur : <center>{{ logged_user|upper }}.</center> </h3></center>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  {% csrf_token %}
  <!-- {{ form.as_p }} -->
  {% for question in questions %}
    <hr>
    <p>
      <label for="question">{{ question }}</label>
      <input type="hidden" id="id_question_{{ question.id }}" name="question" value="{{ question.id }}"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="answer">Réponse :</label>
      <input type="text" id="id_answer_{{ question.id }}" name="answer" />
    </p>  
  {% endfor %}<hr>
  <p>
    <label for="creationDate">Date de création :</label>
    <input type="text" id="id_creationDate" name="creationDate" />
  </p> 
  <p>
    <label for="user"> User : {{ logged_user }}</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="id_user" name="user" /><!-- <select name="{{ logged_user }}" size="1">
      <option id="{{ logged_user.id }}">{{ logged_user }}</option>
    </select> -->
  </p>
  <p>
  <br><br><br>
    <center><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" /></center>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, this is because you generate your custom fields. The **from.save()** method will only take value in form generated with your **<!-- {{ form.as_p }} -->** line.
You cant' use ModelForm if you want edit multiple models in the same time.

Comment: Do you have an exemple with ModelForm for multiple recording ?

Comment: I'm sorry but no. This is not the goal of ModelForm. Try to update many record by using ModelForm is a pretty bad practice. But you can try Django Forms.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define form `action` attribute with proper url  to access your view, right now your `action=""` what is wrong.

So you have to define route and register your view with [Django URLDispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/) then you would be ready to set form action.

Try to work with [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) to get better understanding of how django works.

Your form action should be **`action="access/{id}/"`**, where **{id}** is  id of item page rendered for, but notice that's better to add name to your `url` declaration as in snippet below:

```
url(r'^access/(?P<instance>[0-9]+)/$', views.access, name='access')
```

And use [**{% url %}**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to build form action:

```
action="{% url id %}"
```

Comment: And how i can do that ?

Comment: Show  your `urls.py` file

Comment: @JeremyLgdr Updated answer with additional information

Comment: This is not the problem.